# How do I convert large .yaml files to .json files?

Tags: json, yaml

I am trying to convert some large .yaml files into .json files, and I am running into issues. I am trying to use the npm package [yaml-convert](https://www.npmjs.com/package/yaml-convert), but when the files get too large it stops outputting useable json. Does anyone know of a way I could do this?

Comment: How large is large? A thousand lines? A gigabyte?

Comment: Probably 5000-8000 lines, its starting with 7100 lines of yaml on the largest file

Comment: What's „useable json“? What is the exact problem with the output?